# PHP - Deleting a file listed in a Directory through a hyperlink

Tags: php, directory, unlink

I'm trying to list all files in a directory and delete a file if a 'DELETE' link is clicked, however, it's telling me that the file is non existant showing me these error messages:

```
Notice: Undefined index: dir in C:\xampp\htdocs\Task2PHP\final\deletefile.php on line 4

Warning: unlink(adam.png): No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Task2PHP\final\deletefile.php on line 7
```

files.php (code block):

```
@$selected_path = $_POST['myFiles'];

$dir = $selected_path;

echo "<br>Current files in: " . $dir . " <br /><br />";

if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {


            echo "$file <a href=deletefile.php?file=$file>DELETE</a><br />"; 
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

deletefile.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$dir = $_SESSION['dir'];
$file= basename($_GET['file']);//added

unlink("$file");

?>
```

Comment: make sure the file exists at the location given in the error message or adjust the path when unlinking to point to the correct location. Also, deleting files with a link (GET request) is considered bad practise because spiders will follow these links and clean out your directories.

Comment: make sure you are storing dir in the session, as your first error seems to indicate it cannot find it. (no such index).  also you will need to build out the full path to pass to unlink.

Comment: @Doon How do you exactly pass a variable in a session? I think that is the problem.

Comment: $_SESSION['dir'] = $dir in files.php (after session_start();) has been called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unlink()` function will look for `adam.png` relative to the location of `deletefile.php`. If the image is inside a directory, you'll need to something like this:

```
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$dir = $_SESSION['dir'];
$file= basename($_GET['file']);//added
unlink('folder/container/'.$file); // or maybe you want unlink($dir.$file);
```

Alternatively, you could pass the directory to `deletefile.php` by changing the `echo` statement in your `files.php` to:

```
echo "$file <a href=\"deletefile.php?file=$file&dir=$dir\">DELETE</a><br />";
```

You can then access this inside of `deletefile.php` through `$_GET['dir']`, so your code would be something like:

```
$dir = $_GET['dir'];
$file = basename($_GET['file']);
unlink($dir.$file);
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass the variable containing the directory to deletefile.php ?

Comment: tried that but didn't work. I think it's the variable $dir which is not getting passed to the next page.

Comment: How does the generated HTML link look?

Comment: Thanks.. Worked perfectly!

Comment: Just a quick question, I added  header( 'Location: files.php' ) ; to deletefile.php so when the file is deleted it redirects to files.php, and its showing all the files in C://

Answer (score 0):

It is because `unlink("$file");` $file is only file name it should be either absolute path or proper relative path. Check the path use ../ and ./ to give relative path.